# Controlling distributionManagement based on environment

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I am using Maven 3.0.3 + artifactory + hudson + linux

How can I distinguish & control my <distributionManagement> based on  local & server build.

Because my SIT is linux., where build is taken care by hudson.

and for local want to do build on either on windows / linux .

If build takes place on Local(windows/linux) i should not use  , mean  build should not distribute to artifactory.

How can I control distributionManagement.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look on [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).